# Do magento2 natively support reCaptcha enterprise? How many effort to implement it?If there is third-party support available, could you recommend any?

Tags: magento2, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

I search on the offical document (https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/systems/security/captcha/security-google-recaptcha.html) 
It just say about reCaptcha V2 and reCaptcha V3, none of them mention "reCaptcha Enterprise". 
I have searched in the source code of Adobe Commerce and Magento, but I cannot find the external JavaScript code needed to implement reCaptcha Enterprise (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js) as specified in the documentation ([https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/faq.\](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/faq.%5C)

If you already implement google recaptcha enterprice before would you give me some recommend  please, like where to get sample code, time to implement, ...